# How to build a Quarkus Native Docker ARM64 Container Image in Github Actions?

Tags: github-actions, quarkus, arm64, quarkus-native

I am trying to create an ARM64 based Docker image for my Quarkus native app. There seem to be a lot of discussions but I was unable to find a good, recent and simple working example.
My Github Actions workflow currently works well for building an AMD64 image (see below workflow) but I am having a hard time to adapt this to an ARM64 based Docker image built and being able to run it on my Mac M1. Does anyone have an example or can point me into the right direction?

Thank you

```
name: Generate Docker Image
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'master'
    tags:
      - 'v*'
jobs:
  build:
    name: Build Native Quarkus
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2
      - name:  Checkout Source Code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
      - name: Set up JDK
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          distribution: 'temurin'
          java-version: 17
          check-latest: true
      - name: Cache Maven packages
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: ~/.m2
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-m2-${{ hashFiles('**/pom.xml') }}
          restore-keys: ${{ runner.os }}-m2
      - name: Build Native Quarkus
        run: mvn -B install -Pnative -DskipTests
      - name: Login to DockerHub
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        env:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
        if: ${{env.username != ''}}
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}
      - name: Extract metadata (tags, labels) for Docker
        id: meta
        uses: docker/metadata-action@v4
        with:
          images: test/my-test
          tags: |
            type=ref,event=branch
            type=ref,event=pr
            type=semver,pattern={{version}}
            type=semver,pattern={{major}}.{{minor}}
      - name: Build and push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v4
        if: ${{ github.event_name != 'pull_request' }}
        with:
          context: "."
          file: './src/main/docker/Dockerfile.native'
          platforms: linux/amd64
          push: true
          tags: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
          labels: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.labels }}
```

Dockerfile.native

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi-minimal:8.1
WORKDIR /work/
COPY target/*-runner /work/application

# set up permissions for user `1001`
RUN chmod 775 /work /work/application \
  && chown -R 1001 /work \
  && chmod -R "g+rwX" /work \
  && chown -R 1001:root /work

EXPOSE 8081
USER 1001

CMD ["./application", "-Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0"]
```